# Why do we need to drop_first parameter in get dummy function

Tags: python, data-science, logistic-regression, dummy-variable

I have a question about get dummy function. Why do we need to `drop_first=true` or `false` while getting dummy. What is the purpose of using this parameter?

And I am taking warning in Logistic regression. This is 'The line search algorithm did not converge'. Is there a relation between this warning and `drop_first=false` parameter?

Warning is completely in below,

```
C:\Users\aslii\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py:313: LineSearchWarning: The line search algorithm did not converge
  warn('The line search algorithm did not converge', LineSearchWarning)
C:\Users\aslii\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\optimize.py:195: UserWarning: Line Search failed
  warnings.warn('Line Search failed')
C:\Users\aslii\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py:313: LineSearchWarning: The line search algorithm did not converge
  warn('The line search algorithm did not converge', LineSearchWarning)
C:\Users\aslii\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\optimize.py:195: UserWarning: Line Search failed
  warnings.warn('Line Search failed')
```

Thanks in advance